# pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('Invalid parameter type. param-index=1 param-type=StringVar', 'HY105')

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, insert, db2

I am trying to insert some data to a DB2 using Python. I have a GUI form (TKINTER) to get the data from the user, so in each entry I need to assign a variable, so here is an example:

```
comment = StringVar()

comment_label = Label(text="Comment:", font=("Arial", 12))
comment_label.place(x=20, y=150)
comment_entry = Entry(textvariable=comment, width="110", font=("Arial", 12))
comment_entry.place(x=120, y=150)
```

But when I try to insert this variable I get this error:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('Invalid parameter type.  param-index=1 param-type=StringVar', 'HY105')
```

And btw, this is the insert code:

```
registrar_intervencion_cursor = conn_db2.cursor()
registrar_intervencion_query = "INSERT INTO BIUMO220.TICKREGINTERVENCION(numerador, responsable, fecha, centro, tipo_intervencion, subtipo, comentario, ref_producto_final, df_producto_final, ref_componente, df_componente, util, df_util, tiempo_intervencion) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
registrar_intervencion_cursor.execute(registrar_intervencion_query, numerador, responsable, fecha_hoy, resultado_centro, resultado_intervencion, resultado_subtipo_intervencion, comentario, ref_producto_final, res, ref_componente, componente_row, util, util_row, tiempo_aprox_intervencion)
registrar_intervencion_cursor.commit()
```

Yeah, It's quite a big form, lots of variables.

Comment: Which Db2 Python interface are you using (dbi, db, ...)? And why the cursor()?

Comment: I'm using pyodbc

Comment: Here is the connect code: conn_db2 = pyodbc.connect('DSN=AS400; UID=%s; PWD=%s' % ( uname, password ) )

Comment: please EDIT your question to add missing facts (do not use comments, they get deleted and are not searchable).  Which operating-system runs python (give all details of bitness, version, edition, distro) ?  Which python version? Which version of pyodbc? Which Db2-driver are you using? Have you tried to simplify (that is, make a small test program that does the insert, independently of tkinter etc).

Comment: You need to show your table definition and more of the code, where you define and assign your variables.